# How to add a column in a table from another table having common id column in both the tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a table1 with a Column2 from table2 where id should match while inserting the Column2 values from table2 in table1 for SQL Server.

I tried with the below 2 sets of code, but it is not working.
Can anyone help me out with this?

```
alter table table1
add Column2 varchar(20)

insert into table1
Select t2.Column2
    from table1 as t1
    inner join table2 as t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
```

And, below also:

```
Update table1
Set Column2 = (Select t2.Column2
        from table1 as t1
        inner join table2 as t2
        on t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  But it sounds like you might want `merge`.

Comment: That second query is very likely going to error with "subquery returned more than one row". `table1` in the `FROM` and `table1` in the `UPDATE` clause are **not** the same reference. You should be using an `UPDATE ...SET... FROM... JOIN` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
Update t1
Set Column2 = t2.Column2
    from table1 as t1
    inner join table2 as t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thank you! Working fine.